# ID: aloe or agave?

Tags: identification, aloe

I've been unable to figure out if the plants pictured are aloe or agave, or if they're the same species at all (the smaller one makes me think of aloe more).

Could you help me identify these plants?

The bigger one:
[image: the bigger one]

The smaller one:
[image: the smaller one]

Comment: Agave...larger group of specimens. https://goo.gl/images/vUJeGn

Answer (score 3):

I'm not so sure - some Aloes do have thorns beneath their leaves and on the edges; Aloe marlothii is particularly nasty for sharp thorns. This one could be Aloe ferox, which does have thorns along the edges and on the undersides of the leaves, and looks greyish green or green depending on air humidity  http://n-s-succulents.co.uk/documents/Aloes/aloe-ferox-01.jpg. Aloe melanacantha also has thorns on the edges and under the leaves, but they tend to be in a single row beneath the leaves rather than randomly dotted about.

More varieties of Aloe shown here, but I can't find any that looks exactly like your second picture http://n-s-succulents.co.uk/Aloes-a-n.php

Answer (score 3):

Both definitely Aloes. Pointy leaf tips is pretty characteristic of Aloes too.
First is probably Aloe broomii, dark thorns are quite diagnostic for this species. Not sure about 2nd one. It's just possible they are the same species, if 2 has been in a lot less light than 1 and grown quite etiolated.

Comment: I agree, definitely Aloe. Probably tc'ed broomii in need of light